# Multiple start pages in Durandal

Tags: durandal

I have included my main.js and shell.js below for reference.   As you can see my default route in the shell.js is the viewmodels/search and it has a second route to viewmodels/application with can take an option parameter,  which is the IDKey for a particular application.   Most of the time this is how I want users to enter the system by starting with the search screen where they can search for a particular application or have the option to click a button to start a new application.   However I would like to be able to publish url links that could skip the search page and start the application with the viewmodels/application page with the appropriate IDKey.

I just cannot seem to figure out how to implement this behaviour.  Can anybody get me pointed in the right direction of how to implement this.

MAIN.JS

```
define('jquery', [], function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', [], function () { return ko; });


define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator'], function (system, app, viewLocator) {
    app.title = 'My App';

    //specify which plugins to install and their configuration
    app.configurePlugins({
        router: true,
        dialog: true,
        widget: {
            kinds: ['expander']
        }
    });

    app.start().then(function () {

        toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';
        toastr.options.backgroundpositionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';

        viewLocator.useConvention();

        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');

    });
});
```

SHELL.JS

```
define(['plugins/router'], function (router) {
    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            return router.map([
                { route: '', moduleId: 'viewmodels/search', title: 'Permit Application Search', nav: true },
                { route: 'application(/:id)', moduleId: 'viewmodels/application', title: 'Permit Application', nav: true }
            ]).buildNavigationModel()
              .activate();
        }
    };


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your routes as shown in code, you should simply be able to publish a link like `http://yourdomain.com#application/12`